# building a dynamic query in mysql and golang

Tags: mysql, go

How can I build a dynamic query depending on the parameters that I get?

This example is stupid and the syntax is wrong but you will get the idea of what I want.

I guess that I need to add a slice of variables to the end of the query.

I know how to do it in PHP, but not in golang.

```
db := OpenDB()

defer db.Close()

var filter string

if name != "" {     
filter = filter " AND name = ?" 

}

if surname != "" {  
filter = filter + " AND surname = ?"

}

if address != "" {  
filter =  filter + " AND address = ?" 

}

err = db.Query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = ?" +
filter, login)
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question on how to format the string, the simple answer is to use [fmt.Sprintf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) to structure your string. ***However*** see further down for a quick note on using fmt.Sprintf for db queries:

> Sprintf formats according to a format specifier and returns the resulting string.

Example:

```
query := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='%s'", login)
err = db.Query(query)

// Equivalent to:
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login=?", login)
```

Using this for queries, you're safe from injections. That being said, you might be tempted to modify this and use db.Exec for creations/updates/deletions as well. As a general rule of thumb, **if you use db.Exec with fmt.Sprintf and do not sanitize your inputs first, you open yourself up to sql injections**.

GoPlay with simple example of why fmt.Sprintf with db.Exec is bad:
https://play.golang.org/p/-IWyymAg_Q

You should use [db.Query](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query) or [db.Prepare](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Prepare) in an appropriate way to avoid these sorts of attack vectors. You might have to modify the code sample above to come up with a injection-safe snippet, but hopefully I gave you enough to get started.

Comment: thank you it worked.

your example is safe with SQL injection?

Comment: The example I gave you is not. You should really use prepared statements if you're unsure of the safety of your params. I'll update the answer with the appropriate information.

Comment: Right now your example doesn't make sense - you use `fmt.Sprintf` but there is no format specifier in the string and the parameter `login` is never used. You probably want `rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login=?", login)` as your example.

Comment: Derp, good call and exactly right. I kinda wanted to show both approaches for using fmt.Sprintf to formating his string (which is originally what he was asking) but also touch on the dangers of using that in conjunction with db.Exec. In this case though, he would be fine with either example snippet above (modified to your comment).

Comment: and isn't there other way to make a dynamic query without using `sprintf` ? because i see sprintf too risky

Comment: @ocuparedu you can also use a prepared statement (see my link in the answer I posted).